# custom markdown in user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown, redcarpet

I would like to add a simple markdown to user comments.

When user submits this comment:

**I just got [card:Black Lotus] man. POW!**

I would like it to be display like this:

**I just got Black Lotus man. POW!**

but with extra html markup:

`I just got <span class="preview" data-card="/cards/card.id">Black Lotus</span> man. POW!`

1) I looked at [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) but can't figure out how to add `[card:...]` markdown to it.

2) or should I just run regexp and replace content before saving it to DB and then `sanitize(ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper)` `span` tag before displaying a comment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Defining custom renderer and overwriting normal_text method does a job.

```
class HTMLwithCards < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def preprocess(full_document)
    full_document.gsub(/\[card:(.*)\]/) do
      card = Card.find_by_name($1)
      if card
        "<span class='preview' data-card='/cards/#{card.id}'>#{$1}</span>"
      else
        $1
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
def markdown(text)
  renderer = HTMLwithCards.new(hard_wrap: true, filter_html: true)
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer).render(text).html_safe
end
```

Comment: AFAIK you need to use `preprocess` instead of `normal_text`, so I'm editing this.  If you know something I'm missing, please correct my correction.

Comment: @iconoclast Won't using `preprocess` in this way require you to have `filter_html` off? I think a solution using `normal_text` or `postprocess` would be the way to go here, depending on if you care if your syntax messes up code blocks